# Custom splash screen adding mp4 video(?)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I trying to add a video for my splash screen in my react-native app I added some lines of code and get no errors but the splash screen video doesn't play when starting the app by clicking the icon on an android phone or emulator. I created a folder where the video is. Any feedback is appreciated :)

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Video, Text, Image} from 'react-native'
import Color from '../utils/Colors'
import Images from '../const/Images'
import Constants from '../const/Constants'
import firebase from '../firebase/Firebase'
import Video from   '../video/Video'

function SplashScreen({navigation}){
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        NavigateToAuthORGroupScreen()
    }, [navigation])

   function NavigateToAuthORGroupScreen(){
        
        setTimeout(function (){

           firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
               if (user != null){
                   navigation.reset({
                       index:0,
                        routes: [{name: 'Groups Screen'}]
                   })
               }else{
                   navigation.reset({
                       index:0,
                  routes: [{name: 'SignInScreen'}]
                    })
               }
          })

       },2600)
    }
    

return(
    <View style = {styles.constainer}>
     <Image style = {styles.logo} source = {Images.logo}></Image> 
     <Video style = {styles.video} source = {Images.video} autoPlay loop></Video>
  </View>
)

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    video:{
        width: '100%',
        height: 0.06 * Constants.screenHeight
    },
    logo: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        margin: 0.04 * Constants.screenHeight
    },
    constainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        backgroundColor: Color.vibenote
    }
})
export default SplashScreen
Images.js file: below
const images = {
logo: require('../../assets/logo.png'),
add: require('../../assets/add.png'),
logout: require('../../assets/logout.png'),
groups: require('../../assets/groups.png'),
video: require('../../assets/vnspl.mp4')
```

[image]

Comment: The code in image and the code in text is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can You Please Show the error that you get?

One more thing you called VideoView but I can't see you import any VideoView in your code.

Comment: That is it I'm getting no errors the error to me is that the video doesn't show I. will update VideoView to just video throughout the code thanks for pointing that out.